# Querying a document and returning its subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

High level description. I have a collection named "venues". Each venue has a subcollection named "food". The firestore path is "> venues > {DocumentID} food {DocumentID}"

In SwiftUI, I'm passing the venueID (documentID) and I want to display all of the items in the food collection that relates to the venueID that I'm passing.

I know the venueID is successfully being passed and the selected venueID does in fact have a subcollection of 'food' with multiple documents. Here's what I have right now. I continue to get "The data couldn't be read because it's missing."

```
struct SettingsView: View {
    var body: some View {
//        HStack{
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section("General") {
                    NavigationLink("Applications", value: "app")
                }
                Section("Calendar") {
                    NavigationLink("Outlook", value: "outlook")
                    NavigationLink("Google", value: "gCalendar")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Settings")
            .listStyle(.sidebar)
        }
        VStack {
            // How to change this once the item is clicked?
            ApplicationsView()
        }
//        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ApplicationsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Applications")
    }
}

struct OutlookView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Outlook")
    }
}

struct SettingsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SettingsView()
    }
}

struct Venue: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    let title: String
    let venueArea: String
    let festivalID: String
    let fileURL: String
    let description: String
}

struct FoodItem: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var itemName: String
    var itemDescription: String
    var photoURL: String
    var itemPrice: Int
    var DDPSnack: Bool
    var alcohol: Bool
    var gardenGraze: Bool
    var plantBased: Bool
}

class FoodViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var foodItems = [FoodItem]()

    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var foodRef: CollectionReference?

    init(venueID: String) {
        foodRef = db.collection("venues").document(venueID).collection("food")
        fetchData()
    }

    func fetchData() {
        foodRef?.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error fetching food items: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents found")
                return
            }

            self.foodItems = documents.compactMap { document in
                let result = Result {
                    try document.data(as: FoodItem.self)
                }
                switch result {
                case .success(let foodItem):
                    return foodItem
                case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error decoding food item: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct VenueMenu: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: FoodViewModel
    var venueID: String

    init(venueID: String) {
        self.venueID = venueID
        viewModel = FoodViewModel(venueID: venueID)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(venueID) // display the venueID here
            List(viewModel.foodItems, id: \.id) { foodItem in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(foodItem.itemName)
                    Text("\(foodItem.itemPrice)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You should be using `StateObject`, not `ObservedObject`. 2) You should print the error's full description, not the `localizedDescription`

Comment: Instead of describing what your database looks like, please edit your question and add a screenshot of it. Besides that, tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 print("Error decoding food item: \(error.localizedDescription)")
```

To

```
 print("Error decoding food item: \(error)")
```

You'll get a more descriptive error, you will likely have to make one or more of the variables optional by adding `?` at the end.